# Assign missing variables values based on distribution SAS

Tags: sas

I would like to assign IDs with blank Sizes a size based on the frequency distribution of their Group.

Dataset A contains a snapshot of my data:

```
ID  Group   Size
1   A       Large
2   B       Small
3   C       Small
5   D       Medium
6   C       Large
7   B       Medium
8   B       -
```

Dataset B shows the frequency distribution of the Sizes among the Groups:

```
Group   Small   Medium  Large
A       0.31    0.25    0.44
B       0.43    0.22    0.35
C       0.10    0.13    0.78
D       0.29    0.27    0.44
```

For ID 8, we know that it has a 43% probability of being "small", a 22% probability of being "medium" and a 35% probability of being "large". That's because these are the Size distributions for Group B.

How do I assign ID 8 (and other blank IDs) a Size based on the Group distributions in Dataset B? I'm using SAS 9.4. Macros, SQL, anything is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `table` distribution is ideal for this.  The last datastep here shows that; before that I set things up to create the data at random and determine the frequency table, so you can skip that if you already do that.

See Rick Wicklin's blog about [simulating multinomial data](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/08/07/alternate-ways-to-simulate-multinomial-data.html) for an example of this in other use cases (and more information about the function).

```
*Setting this up to help generate random data;
proc format;
  value sizef
  low - 1.3 = 'Small'
  1.3 <-<2.3  = 'Medium'
  2.3  - high = 'Large'
;
quit;

*Generating random data;
data have;
  call streaminit(7);
  do id = 1 to 1e5;
    group = byte(65+rand('Uniform')*4);   *A = 65, B = 66, etc.;
    size  = put((rank(group)-66)*0.5 + rand('Uniform')*3,sizef.);  *Intentionally making size somewhat linked to group to allow for differences in the frequency;
    if rand('Uniform') < 0.05 then call missing(size); *A separate call to set missingness;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=have;
  by group;
run;

title "Initial frequency of size by group";
proc freq data=have;
  by group;
  tables size/list out=freq_size;
run;
title;

*Transpose to one row per group, needed for table distribution;
proc transpose data=freq_size out=table_size prefix=pct_;
  var percent;
  id size;
  by group;
run;


data want;
  merge have table_size;
  by group;
  array pcts pct_:;  *convenience array;

  if first.group then do _i = 1 to dim(pcts);  *must divide by 100 but only once!;
    pcts[_i] = pcts[_i]/100;
  end;

  if missing(size) then do;
    size_new = rand('table',of pcts[*]);   *table uses the pcts[] array to tell SAS the table of probabilities;
    size = scan(vname(pcts[size_new]),2,'_');
  end;
run;



title "Final frequency of size by group";
proc freq data=want;
  by group;
  tables size/list;
run;
title;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a random value and some if-else logic:

```
proc sql;
    create table temp_assigned as select
        a.*, rand("Uniform") as random_roll, /*generate a random number from 0 to 1*/
        case when missing(size) then
            case when calculated random_roll < small then small
                 when calculated random_roll < sum(small, medium) then medium
                 when calculated random_roll < sum(small, medium, large) then large
            end end as value_selected, /*pick the value of the size associated with that value in each group*/
        coalesce(case when calculated value_selected = small then "Small"
                     when calculated value_selected = medium then "Medium"
                     when calculated value_selected = large then "Large" end, size) as group_assigned /*pick the value associated with that size*/
        from temp as a
        left join freqs as b
        on a.group = b.group;
quit;
```

Obviously you can do this without creating the value_selected variable, but I thought showing it for demonstrative purposes would be helpful.